# VueJS event handlers being rendered before DOM content is completely loaded?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, mousemove, virtual-dom

I am building a Vuejs application, so I am using the `@mousemove` directive in conjunction with [Vue-blotter](https://github.com/arapl3y/vue-blotter). Below, under the "Interaction example" section, I found some base code for manipulating the `<Vue-blotter/>` component properties. So with a minuscule bit of refactoring, I added it to my project and changed the `scope.material.uniforms.uSpeed.value = (e.x + e.y) / 4500` found in the sample to `scope.material.uniforms.uSeed.value = (e.x + e.y) / 2000` also a valid property, as will be shown later. The problem is that if I move the cursor before the page is completely loaded the console will display this error:

> Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'scope.material.uniforms.uSeed')"

This error stops being outputted even if I move the mouse after the page is completely loaded. I am using `Vue-router` and this is how my Home view looks like:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <div class="contact"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/ammarr_yasserr/">Instagram</a><a target="_blank" href="mailto://ammaryasser6.2006@gmail.com">Email</a></div>
    <vue-blotter
    material-type= "LiquidDistortMaterial"
    text= "Portfolio"
    fill= "#EAEBED"
    family= "-apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif"
    :paddingRight= "10"
    :paddingLeft= "10"
    :weight= "700"
    :uniforms= "{
      uSpeed: 0.1,
      uVolatility: 0.03,
      uSeed: 20
    }">
      <div class="hero" slot-scope="{ blotterScope }" @mousemove="(e) => mouseMove(e, blotterScope)">
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem molestiae delectus, consequuntur ad iusto quis ab, natus nisi reiciendis reprehenderit est voluptatum praesentium voluptates nostrum tempore, veritatis repudiandae similique saepe?</p></span>
      </div>
    </vue-blotter>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import '@/assets/stylesheets/Home.sass'
import VueBlotter from 'vue-blotter'
// import gsap from 'gsap'

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  data () {
    return {
      age: null
    }
  },
  components: { VueBlotter },
  created () {
    const birthday = new Date(2006, 1, 8)
    const ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday.getTime()
    const ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs)

    this.age = Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970)
  },
  methods: {
    mouseMove: (e, scope) => {
      scope.material.uniforms.uSeed.value = (e.x + e.y) / 2000
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add check for existing of this object before doing something with it.

Maybe something like this

```
let scope = scope || {};
scope.material = scope.material || {};
scope.material.uniforms = scope.materia.uniforms || {};
scope.material.uniforms.uSeed = scope.material.uniforms.uSeed || {}
```

Comment: Thanks man, this worked really well. Just had to change `let scope` to `let s` and it worked!

Comment: @AmmarSarhan glat that I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing these lines

```
@mousemove="(e) => mouseMove(e, blotterScope)"
```

```
mouseMove: (e, scope) => {
```

to these ones respectively.

```
@mousemove="mouseMove(blotterScope, $event)"
```

```
mouseMove: (scope, e) => {
```

Also, `e.x` should probably be something like `e.target.x` or `e.currentTarget.x`.

---

Let me know if this fixes your error.

Comment: No luck, unfortunately. Still the same error, thanks for your effort though!